# Does "By country" mean "come from those countries"?

Tags: meaning

[A wiki post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refugees_of_the_Syrian_Civil_War) uses "By country" when talking about "Syrian refugees"

[image]

Does "By country" mean "come from those countries" there?

Comment: 'by country' refers to the way refugees are listed country-wise, or classified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try clicking on those links.

They go to articles titled "Refugees of the Syrian Civil War in Turkey", "Refugees of the Syrian Civil War in Lebanon", etc.

So the links are leading to articles about refugees from the Syrian civil war, categorized **by** which **country** they fled to.